# adding string to array and displaying them

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class student {
    public String studentId;
    public String stuName;
    public String stuMajor;
    public String[] stuList;
    private int stuCount = 0;

    public student(String studentId, String stuName, String stuMajor) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.stuName = stuName;
        this.stuMajor = stuMajor;
    }

    public stuList() {
        stuList = new String[10];
    }

    public void joinList(String s) {
        stuList[stuCount++] = s;
    }

    public void displayStudents() {
        for(int i = 0; i < stuCount; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Students #%d: " + stuList[i] + "\n", i + 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Id: %s Name: %s Major: %s", studentId, stuName, stuMajor);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a method for adding students to an array by creating a method and then display them. However I am getting an error in my test file saying

"stuList cannot be resolved to a type. The method displayStudents() is undefined for the type String"

here is my test.java file

```
import week01.package1.student;

public class studentTest {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) { 
        student stu1 = new student("s123", "John", "IT");
        String list = new stuList();
        stu1.joinList(list);
        list.displayStudents();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `displayStudents` on the list, you can only call it on a instance of `student`

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: `String list = new stuList();` is plain wrong syntax. The real answer here is that every character you put in your code **matters**. You have to understand what you are writing down. Meaning: you have to **learn** what `new` means, and how to use it. Hint: not in front of the name of a **method** that sits in your class.

Comment: And a note on the conceptual problem: a Student is just that: a single student. There is NO point in using the Student class to be anything else than: the representation of a single student. So: the ability to hold multiple Student objects does NOT belong into the Student class itself. If at all, you would write *another* class ListOfStudents or something that exists on its own, and to which you can then ADD Student objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my recommendation. First a couple conventions.

- class names start with an uppercase letter
- fields and methods start with lower case and are usually in `camelCase`.
- make fields private and use getters/setters to preserve/enforce encapsulation

Also, a class usually has fields and items that pertain to that class. A `record` could also be used here if the class is immutable.

Knowledge of other students does not make sense for a `Student` class.  A more obvious example might be a `Book` class which has info about a particular book, not all books.  However, a `Library` or `Shelf` class would certainly be appropriate for books depending on the use case.

For students, you could have a `Class` class which might have the name of the class and a list of students attending that class.

```
class Class {
    private String className;
    private List<Student> attendees = new ArrayList<>();

    public Class(String name) {
        this.className = name;
    }
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        System.out.println("Adding: " + student);
        attendees.add(student);
    }
    
    public void displayAttendees() {
        attendees.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    
    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
}
```

I also recommend `Lists` over `arrays` since they can grow dynamically thus eliminating the need to track indices or resize the array.

Having said the above, here is how it might look;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Student {
    private String studentId;
    private String stuName;
    private String stuMajor;

    public Student(String studentId, String stuName, String stuMajor) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.stuName = stuName;
        this.stuMajor = stuMajor;
    }
    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public String getStuName() {
        return stuName;
    }
    public String getStuMajor() {
        return stuMajor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Id: %s, Name: %s, Major: %s", studentId, stuName, stuMajor);
    }
}

public class AddStudentsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class philosophy = new Class("philosophy");
        philosophy.addStudent(new Student("1", "Mary", "Computer Science" ));
        philosophy.addStudent(new Student("2",  "John", "Engineering" ));
        philosophy.addStudent(new Student("3", "Bob", "History" ));
        philosophy.addStudent(new Student("4", "Jill", "Physics" ));
        philosophy.addStudent(new Student("5", "Wendy", "Sociology" ));
        System.out.println();
        philosophy.displayAttendees();
    }

}
```

prints

```
Adding: Id: 1, Name: Mary, Major: Computer Science
Adding: Id: 2, Name: John, Major: Engineering
Adding: Id: 3, Name: Bob, Major: History
Adding: Id: 4, Name: Jill, Major: Physics
Adding: Id: 5, Name: Wendy, Major: Sociology

Id: 1, Name: Mary, Major: Computer Science
Id: 2, Name: John, Major: Engineering
Id: 3, Name: Bob, Major: History
Id: 4, Name: Jill, Major: Physics
Id: 5, Name: Wendy, Major: Sociology
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a little bit. But u should not have a list of students in the students class.

It's better if you create a class like Classroom and then it stores a list of instances of stundent.

And to avoid [OutOfBounds](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-index-out-of-bounds-exception-in-java/) exceptions, I would use an [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) instead of an Array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)       
    {
        Student stu1 = new Student("s123", "John", "IT");

        stu1.stuList();

        stu1.joinList("s123");

        stu1.displayStudents();

    }


    public class Student {
       public String studentId;
       public String stuName;
       public String stuMajor;
       public String[] stuList;
       private int stuCount = 0;

       public Student(String studentId, String stuName, String stuMajor) {
           this.studentId = studentId;
           this.stuName = stuName;
           this.stuMajor = stuMajor;

       }

       public void stuList() {
           stuList = new String[10];
       }

       public void joinList(String s) {
           stuList[stuCount++] = s;
       }

       public void displayStudents() {
           for(int i = 0; i < stuCount; i++) {
               System.out.printf("Students #%d: " + stuList[i] + "\n", i + 1);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return String.format("Id: %s Name: %s Major: %s", studentId, stuName, stuMajor);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't address AT ALL the conceptual problem in that code: a single Student object is NOT the "place" to keep a list of students. Those are two completely DIFFERENT things, and they should never be lumped into the same class.

Comment: I know, that's why I added the second sentence in my statement. The code should only solve the creator's problem so that he can easily understand the solution